# sudo yum install httpd is throwing errors

Tags: yum, httpd, sudo

Hello this is the command im typing and its returning the error you see, any suggestions please

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-46 ~]$ sudo yum install httpd


Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.3.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.27-1.3.amzn1 for package: httpd-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.27-1.3.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.10-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.10
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.10-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.10
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-46 ~]$
```

when I do yum install --skip-broken httpd it returns :

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    httpd-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64 from amzn-updates
    httpd-tools-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64 from amzn-updates
```

Comment: So what have you tried to resolve the problem? What research have you done on your own? We frown on people that just dump errors here and expect a "free" resolution without showing that they've put some effort into it before coming here.

Comment: I have spent the last 4 hours looking up other questions, read about package  conflict. I know its a version conflict, I updated to php 5.5 from 5.3 and now its throwing this error.At this point I dont mind paying you to help me fix this ... I am stuck and need to move forward I have an app to code and been stuck on this part.any input would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to install the `httpd` package, containing version 2.2 of Apache, but you already have `httpd24`, containing version 2.4 of Apache, installed.

Before doing anything else, first decide which version you actually want.

Comment: the newest that will work with php 5.5

Comment: You already have it installed! Why are you trying to install an older version?

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-46 ~]$ sudo service httpd restart
httpd: unrecognized service
it says its not recognized. its not running either.I ran pgrep apache and pgrep apache2 and it doesnt return any thing

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about that, then.

Comment: are you able to help with that Michael ? and thanks for the input !

Comment: nevermind I figured it out thanks Michael for pointing me to the right direction